# How to find the correct subdevision location given the total length, number of total subdevisions, and the location on that length?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am working on a programing problem that I just cant seem to get the formula working correctly. Here is the problem:

Given that a length `L` is subdivided `n` times, find what subdivision length `x` belongs too given that `x < L`. Here is a picture to better illustrate (first time asking a question so it is in ASCII):

```
             x
    0 ------ * ---------- ... ------- L
    ---------------------     ---------
    |  1  |  2  |  3  |   ...   |  n  |
    ---------------------     ---------
```

Visually, x belongs to subdivision 2, but how do you find the formula for the general case where `n` or `L` could be any real positive number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you think of $L$ as a ruler, numbered from  0 to n, as shown in the diagram below.

```
             x
    0 ------ * ---------- ... ------- L
    ---------------------     ---------
    |  1  |  2  |  3  |   ...   |  n  |
    ---------------------     ---------
    0     1     2     3        n-1    n
```

Now, the size of the unit is $L/n$. so we see that the number $x$ represents a real number $xn/L$.  It is then necessary to round this up to the next mark, which has the same name as the section, or round it down and add 1, so eg

$$ X = 1 + \operatorname{int}(xn/L) $$

will convert $x$ into the section it falls in $X$.